# Login via CSS Selector for Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Java and Selenium. I am trying to login to a site that has a unique id for username and password so I figured I would use css to locate the login fields. I am able to do this in Selenium IDE but not in Eclipse.

```
<input name="uid_578180ab6f188bd2803df958f4aafa6c399bc8fe" class="form-control 
col-sm-10" id="uid_578180ab6f188bd2803df958f4aafa6c399bc8fe" autofocus="" 
required="" type="text">
```

I am able to launch the website but the username and password fields remain blank.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id^=uid_]")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("[id^=pwd_]")).sendKeys("password");
```

This is for the password field. Maybe my approach to this is incorrect.

```
<input type="password" required="" class="form-control" 
id="pwd_28e13d5a226a4a576f54de3e0501f2ce1b8204ee" 
name="pwd_28e13d5a226a4a576f54de3e0501f2ce1b8204ee" 
onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)
{document.getElementById('login_form').submit();}">
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS - is styling tecnology, it used selectors (.classes and #id's) to locate elements.
Java can use selectors to find elements. It's smart to use classes if you want to find many elements and ID's for unique (single) element.

```
driver.getElementById("uid_578180ab6f188bd2803df958f4aafa6c399bc8fe").sendKeys("username");
driver.getElementById("pwd_28e13d5a226a4a576f54de3e0501f2ce1b8204ee").sendKeys("password");
```

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say that the uid and pwd are dynamic so upon each new instance, the string after uid_ and pwd_ will change.

Comment: Well, you can assign classes: .password and .username to your inputs and work with it normal way, but you can't be sure that you selecting a single element with a class. Working with unique ID's by selecting only parts of ID's names - is not correct (because you might select more then 1 ID). Also, 1 element can't be assigned with 2 different ID's.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by assigning class using .password and .username to my inputs. I thought using something like this below would work but it seems to not be inputting the keys.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='uid_']")).sendKeys("username")

Comment: class="form-control col-sm-10 username"
.getElementsByClass("username")

Comment: I cannot modify the HTML to that in order for the class to work. I believe the ids are dynamic due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your solution. It should work if there is only one element that starts with "**uid**" or "**pwd**" on a web page.

You can try putting a little wait and check. If the path you have identified is unique, the text will be entered in both **username** and **password** fields